# ssh command crashes after key exchange

Tags: ssh, terminal

Had this strange issue crop up today that I haven't experienced before. I execute `ssh <remote ip>` and ssh crashes with the following exception:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _timingsafe_bcmp
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _timingsafe_bcmp
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

I have run the command with the verbose flag and can see this is happening directly after the key exchange between the local machine and remote host.

**Things I have tried:**

- Restarting terminal
- Restarting machine
- Removing all ssh programs in /usr/bin and replacing them with those of a colleagues mac
- Booting to recovery mode and replacing libSystem.B.dylib with the one that ships with macOS
- Installing openssh with homebrew
- Removing openssh
- Adding a PATH to /usr/bin

Note the same error appears on other commands such as `scp`.

Comment: See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Federico linked github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/716 which suggests this may be a bug with macOS

Like the OP on that post, I was on 10.12.0 and have just updated to 10.12.3. It solved the problem.